# How to add src files in the middle of a pipe

Tags: coffeescript, gulp

I want to process some files with 'coffee', add some js files, concat and minify.

This does not work, coffee fails on the regular js files:

```
gulp.task 'build-js', ->
  gulp.src([
      "bower_components/mbdev-core/dist/js/db.js"
      "bower_components/mbdev-core/dist/js/utils.js"
      "src/js/config/app.coffee"
      "src/js/config/app-db.coffee"              
      "src/js/accounts/accounts.coffee"
      "src/js/budget_items/budget_items.coffee"
      "src/js/line_items/line_items.coffee"
      "src/js/misc/misc.coffee"
      "src/js/reports/report_generators.coffee"
      "src/js/reports/reports.coffee"
   ])
  .pipe(coffee()).on('error', gutil.log)
  .pipe(concat('app.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'))
```

Is there a way to add files after the coffee part?

Comment: You can try using `combine` from the gulp-util module.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You don't need to add files to the original src, but rather to use coffee only "if"...

So, use `gulp-if`

```
gulp.task('task', function() {
  gulp.src('./stuff/*')
    .pipe(gulpif(/[.]coffee$/, coffee()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

See [here](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if) more about gulp-if.

Comment: That's awesome.  I didn't know gulp-if had all those extra features.  You can do a lot with it!

Comment: Yes, I'm learning to love it and trashed a number of my own monkeying-helpers :)

Comment: Actually i have a problem with gulpif. Link to issue: https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if/issues/40
When i am doing watch, and having compilation error, it breaks watch process :(

Answer (score 17):

@Contra 's answer doesn't work for me. New stream replaced the old one, not joined them.

You should combine streams in this way:

```
es = require("event-stream")

es.concat(
  gulp.src('*.coffee')
  .pipe(coffee()),
  gulp.src('*.js')
).pipe(concat('all.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
```

And you can see official guide about this here [Using multiple sources in one task](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md)

If you care about the order inside the stream, you should use `streamqueue` instead of `event-stream`

Comment: Streamqueue doesn't handle errors properly, especially with things like gulp-jshint :-/

Comment: Won't this also lose the file order if they needed to be in the specific order of the original file array?

Comment: Contra's answer is valid starting from gulp v 4.0.0

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [gulp-add-src](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-add-src) plugin:

```
addsrc = require 'gulp-add-src'

gulp.task 'build-js', ->
  gulp.src(['src/coffee/*.coffee'])
    .pipe(coffee()).on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(addsrc(['src/js/somefile.js', 'src/js/otherfile.js']))
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'))
```

Comment: What if i need *.js files to be first in order?

Comment: This plugin is deprecated.

Answer (score 13):

gulp.src streams are passthroughs so you can add them at any point in the pipeline

```
gulp.task 'build-js', ->
  gulp.src([
      "src/js/config/app.coffee"
      "src/js/config/app-db.coffee"              
      "src/js/accounts/accounts.coffee"
      "src/js/budget_items/budget_items.coffee"
      "src/js/line_items/line_items.coffee"
      "src/js/misc/misc.coffee"
      "src/js/reports/report_generators.coffee"
      "src/js/reports/reports.coffee"
  ])
  .pipe(coffee()).on('error', gutil.log)
  .pipe(gulp.src([
      "bower_components/mbdev-core/dist/js/db.js"
      "bower_components/mbdev-core/dist/js/utils.js"
  ]))
  .pipe(concat('app.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'))
```

Comment: This would be great but it doesn't work for me. I only get the files from the last gulp.src

Comment: I have the same issue where the last gulp.src wins, is this a bug or a special gulp option?

Comment: I've seen this mentioned in other places, but gulp doesn't seem to treat gulp.src streams this way anymore.

Comment: Wow, -1? This is way too funny. Cuz, ya know, this guy WROTE GULP. But whatevs.

Comment: Also, just had to come back to this, and this answer does in fact work. Make sure you're not just adding another '.src' to the mix - it needs to go inside of a pipe method call. This really should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Only fixed in Gulp 4.x: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/840#issuecomment-74822819

Comment: In gulp 3.9.1, last gulp.src wins.

Comment: you need to add the option { passthrough: true } to the merged stream or am I missing something?

Comment: No longer works - just replaces the previous stream contents