# How to prepend already minified files in a single Gulpjs task?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, gulp

I'd like to try out Gulpjs as it seems really fast. I can't understand how translate the following (part of) Gruntjs configuration in Gulpjs.

Basically the purpose is **uglify project files plus some external dependencies** (not yet minified) **and prepend some dependencies already minified**, in order to avoid the minification process on already minified sources.

```
uglify: {
    dist: {
        src: [
            '<%= deps %>/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js',
            '<%= deps %>/smalot-bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/locales/*.js',
            'src/js/**/*.js',
        ],
        dest: '<%= clean.dist %>/js/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
    }
},

concat: {
    dist: {
        src: [
            '<%= deps %>/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
            '<%= deps %>/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
            '<%= deps %>/momentjs/min/moment-with-langs.min.js',
            '<%= uglify.dist.dest %>'
        ],
        dest: '<%= uglify.dist.dest %>'
    }
},
```

How can I do the same thing in Gulpjs? Is this even possible?

Right now my task (not working, result is just content of `jquery.min.js`) looks like:

```
gulp.task('uglify', function() {
    gulp.src([
        './bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js',
        './bower_components/smalot-bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/locales/*.js',
        './src/js/**/*.js'
    ])
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('admin-template.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});

// Doesn't work
gulp.task('concat', ['uglify'], function () {
    gulp.src([
        'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        './dist/js/admin-template.js' // output of uglify task
    ])
    .pipe(concat('admin-template.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the stream from your "uglify" task (or use [another method](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support)) if you want your "concat" task to depend on your "uglify" task successful completion.

Either way, you should certainly simplify this.

You may have a look at this [other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719833/gulp-how-to-add-src-files-in-the-middle-of-a-pipe/21723513) for ideas. I would probably use gulp-if, or event-stream.

And take a look over here as well: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md

Comment: Thanks for the useful resouces. I think I'll go for streams queue (need to study that).