# How to use gulp-if to conditionally compile less files?

Tags: gulp, gulp-if

I can't get [gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-if) to work correctly.

Without gulp-if it works fine:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src([
    //  'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'app/stylesheets/main.less',
    ])
    .pipe(less({
        strictMath: true,
         strictUnits: true,
    }))
    .pipe(concat('all.css', {newLine: '\n'}))
    .pipe(prefixer('> 1%'))
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});
```

But as soon as I add `gulp-if` into the mix, the `gulpif` pipe returns nothing when it returns to the main stream:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'app/stylesheets/main.less',
    ])

        .pipe(gulpif(/\.less$/,less({
            strictMath: true,
            strictUnits: true,
        })))
        .pipe(concat('all.css', {newLine: '\n'}))
        .pipe(prefixer('> 1%'))
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});
```

Why is that? What am I doing wrong? If I add some logs into the `gulp-if` source code I can see that the condition *is* passing.

Answer (score 12):

I think you may want to use `gulp-filter` instead: https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-filter

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    var lessFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.less', {restore: true})
    return gulp.src([
        'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'app/stylesheets/main.less',
    ])

    .pipe(lessFilter)
    .pipe(less({
        strictMath: true,
        strictUnits: true,
    }))
    .pipe(lessFilter.restore)

    .pipe(concat('all.css', {newLine: '\n'}))
    .pipe(prefixer('> 1%'))
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});
```

This will create a filtered stream and the `restore()` will restore the stream. `gulpIf` is made to conditionally process a whole stream and not just matching files.

```
gulp.src('src/**/*.js', function () {
    .pipe(gulpIf(isProduction, concat('all.js')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/')
});
```

Comment: I'll give `gulp-filter` a whirl, but I still don't understand what `gulp-if` wouldn't work. I've seen it [used to compile coffeescript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21723513/65387) before.

Comment: You are right. `gulp-if` uses `gulp-match` which should process regular expressions. This should also be valid as well: `.pipe(gulpIf('**/*.less'),less(lessOptions))`

Comment: gulp-if and gulp-filter serve different needs.  gulp-filter removes things from the stream that match the filter.  gulp-if is a ternary-stream passing things to the if and else streams if it matches, and then passes everything downstream.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a bug in `gulp-if`.  Try upgrading `gulp-if` to the latest version, and if that doesn't work, post an issue on https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if/issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    var condition = function(file) {
        if (file.extname == '.less') return true;
    };

    return gulp.src([
        'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'app/stylesheets/main.less',
     ])
    .pipe(gulpif(condition, less({
        strictMath: true,
        strictUnits: true,
    })))
    .pipe(concat('all.css', {newLine: '\n'}))
    .pipe(prefixer('> 1%'))
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});
```

Comment: What are you saying? That `gulpif` will work with a function but not a regex?

Comment: Really? Because the docs [specifically say](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if#condition) that accepts a RegularExpression.